# Can't Install OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I've been trying to install OpenCV (for python dev) on my computer but have been having no luck.

I tried running `brew install opencv` but I am getting a 404 from

`http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/sites/default/files/software_releases/source/tbb41_20121003oss_src.tgz`

```
$ uname -a
Darwin 12.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.2.0: root:xnu-2050.18.24~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try `brew update` followed by `brew install opencv`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also struggled to install opencv using homebrew. I think it had to do with multiple version of python installed. You can check that using

```
python --version
```

This is what ended up working for me. Can't guarantee success for anyone else:

1. Uninstall opencv if you already did with homebrew

   `$ brew uninstall opencv`
2. Use the selfupdate command on macports

   `$ sudo port selfupdate`
3. Then upgrade installed ports

   `$ port upgrade outdated`
4. Reinstall opencv with homebrew

   `$ brew install opencv`
5. At that point, it told me to add the following to my ~/.bash_profile

   `export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH`

You can test with

```
$ python
>> import cv2
```

I noticed this procedure reduced my multiple versions of python to just python 2.7.5. There's probably a better way to do this, but give it a shot.

Hope that helps!

Comment: `import cv2` as you have probably installed OpenCV 2.x

Answer (score 1):

you should follow the steps here: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_OpenCV_Port

you can also try building from source

Comment: When I use `sudo port install opencv +python27`, everything compiles just find, but I get an import error when python tries to import cv.

Answer (score 0):

After trying every single method out there,none of them worked for me. Finally found way to install opencv using this command.
For python 3-
`pip3 install opencv-contrib-python`
For python 2-
`pip install opencv-contrib-python`